# Green Identities via Differential Forms

Tags: manifolds, vector-analysis

What is the actual meaning of the [Green identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities):

[image]

[image]

Is there a picture/geometric interpretation of these, as well as intuition going beyond the usual integration-by-parts meaning associated to these identites? For instance, why do they really arise in the Green function for Poisson's equation.

There should be a nice way to interpret these [geometrically in terms of differential forms](http://em.groups.et.byu.net/pdfs/publications/formsj.pdf), where you derive the second one by subtracting

$$d(\psi \wedge * d \phi ) = d \psi \wedge * d \phi + \psi d * d \phi = d \phi \wedge * d \psi + \psi \nabla ^2 \phi * 1$$

from

$$d(\phi \wedge * d \psi ) = d \phi \wedge * d \psi + \phi d * d \psi = d \phi \wedge * d \psi + \phi \nabla ^2 \psi * 1$$

to get

$$d(\phi \wedge * d \psi) - d( \phi \wedge * d \psi ) = d(\phi * d \psi - \phi  * d \psi ) = (\phi \nabla ^2 \psi - \psi \nabla ^2 \phi)* 1$$

which, by Stokes theorem, gives

$$\int _{V} (\phi \nabla ^2 \psi - \psi \nabla ^2 \phi)* 1 = \int _{V} d(\phi * d \psi - \phi  * d \psi ) = \int _{\partial V} (\phi * d \psi - \phi  * d \psi ) $$

We know Stokes theorem has a pictorial interpretation:

[image]

as does the Hodge star, so what about the Green identities? There should be pictorial meaning to every step of those calculations...

Comment: Thank you for the diff form and electromagnetics paper.

Comment: I think this version of the paper is better
http://125.71.228.222/wlxt/ncourse/dccydcb/web/condition/9.pdf